# Masonry overlapping with ImagesLoaded without Infinite Scroll in Tumblr

Tags: jquery, masonry

first time here.
I'm trying to create my custom tumblr theme with 3 columns using Masonry plugin but i'm not going so well. The posts are overlapping and I'm not even using Infinite Scroll. I tried to use $(window).load(...) but it didn't work, I tried to use ImagesLoaded but it didn't work too, help me please ^-^
This is how the page is loading: http://s16.postimg.org/u17syta51/image.jpg, if I resize/refresh the page they go to the right position. This is my full code: http://pastebin.com/VLzwEfgP and my test tumblr url is **entertain-us.tumblr.com** (I can't put +2 links). Obs: the theme isn't complete yet because I don't know how to solve this problem.

jQuery (this is before `</body>`):

```
var $container = ('section#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: 'article.post',
        columnWidth: 400,
        isFitWidth: true,
    });
});
```

CSS

```
section#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    max-width: 1250px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

article.post {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

article.post:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Almost 2 years I don't program, so if I did any stupid mistake in my code, I would appreciate to know haha

Sorry any english mistake and thank you for your attention :D

--- SOLUTION ---

To solve the overlapping problem, as Macsupport said, I just needed to put the Masonry code inside $(document).ready, this way

```
var $container = $('section#container');    
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 400,
            itemSelector: 'article.post',
            isFitWidth: true
        });
    });
});
```

I put the `var $container = $('section#container');` before `$(document).ready();` because the script was changing my container width to 800px (making only 1 column) and when I set the variable before activate the script it will not change it's width, I could just put `isResizeBound: false` inside masonry, but I still going to try make this layout change it's layout depending on window size, when I get success at it I'll update here. But for now the overlapping problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your js.

You are are missing the $ for jquery in your container variable:

```
 var $container = ('section#container');
```

Should be this:

```
 var $container = $('section#container');
```

Try this code:

```
    var $container = $('section#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: 'article.post',
                columnWidth: 400,
                isFitWidth: true
            });
        });
```

ADDENDUM

Put this code inside your

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 });
```

not outside of it, as it is now.
 Also, why did you rename your imagesLoaded.js?

Comment: Oh my god haha thank you. And an information: I had to put the code back in the <head> because it wasn't working before </body>. Well, I thought that's was all but the posts still overlapping :/

Comment: I did, that should make the page load and then activate the plugin, making the posts change position to the 3 columns layout, right? Well, it's doing the opposite, it's loading with the masonry layout and changing position to 1 column layout lol. About the imagesLoaded script, I don't remember exactly why I rename it xD

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are setting your #container to only 800px wide ( Use your developer tools to see it). Since your columnWidth is set at 400px, along with margin etc. there is no room for a second column. This is not something related to masonry I think.

Comment: #container width changes responsively from 400-800-1200 etc as the browser width changes. This is why it is one column (or 2 if the browser is large enough)

Comment: It's because Masonry script changes the layout depending in the browser size, that's why I set "max-width" and not "width", so it could has less than 3 columns but no more than that. I tried to put the "var $container=$(..);" before document.ready and it worked, but the layout isn't changing when I resize the browser. So, I guess Masonry set container width to "800px" and if I get the section#container selector in the variable before the plugin is activated, it will not change it's width. For now, it's good, it's working, I'll edit the question with final code, thank you very much xD

Comment: Was just fine but now it's not working again -.- well, the overlapping problem was solved at least, I'll try to figure out what in the hell is resizing the #container, or just try to resize it back with jQuery and reload the script, idk..